# The class 'Jiffy' doesn't have an unnamed constructor. Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'Jiffy'

Tags: flutter

```
// ignore_for_file: unused_element

import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jiffy/jiffy.dart';

import '../../helpers.dart';
import '../models/models.dart';
import '../widgets/widgets.dart';

class MessagesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessagesPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        const SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: _Stories(),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(_delegate),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _delegate(BuildContext context, int index) {
    final Faker faker = Faker();
    final date = Helpers.randomDate();
    return _MessageTitle(
      messageData: MessageData(
        senderName: faker.person.name(),
        message: faker.lorem.sentence(),
        messageDate: date,
        dateMessage: Jiffy(date).fromNow(),
        profilePicture: Helpers.randomPictureUrl(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _MessageTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MessageTitle({super.key, required this.messageData});

  final MessageData messageData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class _Stories extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Stories({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      elevation: 0,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 134,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 16.0,
                top: 8,
                bottom: 16,
              ),
              child: Text(
                "Stories",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: AppColors.textFaded,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final faker = Faker();
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 60,
                      child: _StoryCard(
                        storyData: StoryData(
                          name: faker.person.name(),
                          url: Helpers.randomPictureUrl(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _StoryCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const _StoryCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.storyData,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final StoryData storyData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Avatar.medium(url: storyData.url),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
            child: Text(
              storyData.name,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 11,
                letterSpacing: 0.3,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> The class 'Jiffy' doesn't have an unnamed constructor. Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'Jiffy'

from here:

```
dateMessage: Jiffy(date).fromNow(),
             ^
```

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong in this line: `dateMessage: Jiffy(date).fromNow()`

It should be like this `Jiffy.parse('1997/09/23').fromNow()`, here replace the actual date with your `date` variable.

Comment: Error resolved thank you very much